# Как настроить layout, чтобы виджеты сразу вставали вначале, а не в центре формы?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlayout

В общем у меня сейчас форма выглядит так, но нужно, чтобы эти виджеты были вначале формы.

[image]

Пытался подвинуть виджеты с помощью большого виджета, но в коде получается несуразица

[image]

Вопрос: Есть ли какая то настройка, чтобы оно сразу добавлялось в начало формы?

Вот код, который частично решает проблему с помощью дополнительного виджета.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QRect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QGridLayout, QDockWidget, QListWidget, QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class GUI(QWidget):
    #Problem Widgets
    Widgets = [0]


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        #grid layout
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.ProblemLayout = QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QRect(10, 80, 390, 950))

        #Buttons
        btnAdd = QPushButton('Add', self)
        btnAdd.resize(60, 40)
        btnAdd.move(10, 30)
        btnAdd.clicked.connect(self.AddProblem)

        #Window
        self.setGeometry(500, 150, 1000, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Planner')
        #self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('images/icon/icon.png'))

        self.show()

    def UpdateProblem(self):
        del GUI.Widgets[-2]
        self.widget.hide()
        for i in reversed(range(self.ProblemLayout.count())): 
            widgetToRemove = self.ProblemLayout.itemAt(i).widget()
            # remove it from the layout list
            self.ProblemLayout.removeWidget(widgetToRemove)
            # remove it from the gui
            widgetToRemove.setParent(None)

        widget = QListWidget(self)
        GUI.Widgets.append(widget)

        for i in range(len(GUI.Widgets)-1):
            for j in range(len(GUI.Widgets[i])):
                self.ProblemLayout.addWidget(GUI.Widgets[i][j], i, j)
        self.ProblemLayout.addWidget(GUI.Widgets[-1], len(GUI.Widgets), 1)

        self.widget.show()

    def AddProblem(self):

        self.lineEditP = QLineEdit(self)

        self.btnP = QPushButton('More', self)

        GUI.Widgets.append([self.lineEditP, self.btnP])

        self.UpdateProblem()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Как это должно выглядеть в конечном итоге?

Comment: Опубликуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: @S. Nick обновил. Пробовал вашим способом, но натыкался на проблему обновления формы, где я удаляю все виджеты с формы а затем добавляю обновленный список. Часть кода, которая удаляет, как я понял, ориентирована только на виджеты, которым SpacerItem не является.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>718</width>
    <height>422</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
        <property name="text">
         <string>PushButton</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
        <property name="text">
         <string>PushButton</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
        <property name="text">
         <string>PushButton</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="3">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
        <property name="text">
         <string>PushButton</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="2">
       <widget class="QSpinBox" name="spinBox"/>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="4">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_5">
        <property name="text">
         <string>...</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox">
        <property name="text">
         <string>CheckBox</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1">
       <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>20</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>718</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Действительно, подошло. Но, теперь другая проблема. Я делаю это не через designer, и у меня возникает ошибка при добавлении этого элемента: addWidget(self, QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QSpacerItem'

Я не совсем понимаю вашу идею, но попробуйте пример ниже:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QRect, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QAction, 
    qApp, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QGridLayout, QDockWidget, QListWidget, 
    QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class GUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.i = 0
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        btnAdd = QPushButton('Add')
        btnAdd.clicked.connect(self.addProblem)
        #grid layout
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)        
        self.layout.addWidget(btnAdd, self.i, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft )
        self.layout.setRowStretch(111, 1)
        self.i += 1

    def addProblem(self):
        lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        btn = QPushButton(f'More {self.i}')
        self.layout.addWidget(lineEdit, self.i, 0)
        btn.clicked.connect(lambda ch, l=lineEdit: print(l.text()))
        self.layout.addWidget(btn, self.i, 1)
        self.i += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = GUI()
    gui.setWindowTitle('Planner')
    gui.resize(300, 400)
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Действительно, подошло. Но, теперь другая проблема. Я делаю это не через designer, и у меня возникает ошибка при добавлении этого элемента: addWidget(self, QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QSpacerItem'.

Comment: @qwerty  Странно получается, рисуете одно, а делаете другое. Опубликуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: @qwerty я добавил обновление в свой ответ

Comment: @qwerty скажите пожалуйста, данный вопрос решен или нет?

Comment: Да, все получилось. Спасибо)

Comment: @qwerty мой ответ вам чем-то помог ?

Comment: Да, я принял его, если Вы об этом. Благодарю ещё раз